# Automatically refresh cell formulas with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have following formula

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY('Id match'!A2:B,"SELECT A,B WHERE B matches '"& TEXT(TEXTJOIN("|",1,FILTER(W3:W30,W3:W30<>"",W3:W30<>0)),0)&"' ",0))
```

That is Querying results if the item is contained in a list. So far so good. This function needs to constantly evaluate the input from Cell `W3:W30`. However as soon as I close the sheet, this continuation seems to stop & the Formula returns to the result `"#N/A"`. Repasting the formula does the trick but I dont want to do this over and over.

It is worth mentioning that the query input is based on another query!

I read that `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` in an Apps Script might help, but for me it does not. Also I am a bit confused how I tell the script which spreadsheet to update.

Has anyone an idea to approach this issue and keep the formula working at all times

Comment: First approach: there might be cases where iferror(function, iferror(function, function)function) should work. For me it does not

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, so this spreadsheet has some kind of output, or is serving data to another spreadsheet, which is why you need constant execution? Or are you trying to track some kind of data? If this is the case, won't apps script time driven triggers work for you? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/